# Site Header Responsiveness

Tags: html, css

TLDR: The site gains a horizontal scroll bar around width 460px and I'm stumped.

New to learning web development, I've learned a bit about working with grid and flexbox, but I still struggle at times with making sections of a site responsive. In this current personal project, I'm aiming to make a header section that completely fills the screen for one section and the desktop/larger layout isn't too bad. However, I can't seem to fix what's causing the horizontal scroll bar to appear around 460px width; it seems to be a padding issue but I can't seem to target the padding and reduce it with media queries. Any help is very much appreciated.

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
}
 :root {
     --transition-duration: 0.3s;
     --font-size-title: calc(2rem + 2vw);
}
 html {
     --color-primary: hsl(274, 99%, 72%);
     --color-primary-m: rgb(241, 172, 255);
     --color-secondary: hsl(274, 99%, 72%, 0.6);
     --color-secondary-m: rgba(207, 56, 200, 0.815);
     --color-secondary-m-dark: purple;
     --color-quaternary: rgb(0, 0, 255);
     --color-tertiary: #f6eedf;
     --color-tertiary-m-light: hsla(39, 56%, 92%, 0.55);
}
 .container {
     display: grid;
     line-height: 1.7;
     width: 100vw;
}
 header#home {
     background-color: var(--color-primary);
     grid-column: container-start / container-end;
     background: linear-gradient(var(--color-primary), var(--color-primary-m));
     background-size: cover;
     background-attachment: fixed;
}
 .header-logo-content {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(30rem, 1fr) 1fr;
     grid-template-rows: min-content;
     height: 90%;
     justify-content: center;
     height: 100vh;
}
 .header-logo-content-logo {
     justify-self: center;
     grid-column: 2 / 3;
     letter-spacing: 0.2rem;
}
 .header-logo-content-content {
     grid-column: 1 / -1;
     align-self: center;
}
 .header-logo-content-title {
     font-size: calc(2rem + 2vw);
     font-weight: 300;
     color: var(--color-secondary-m);
     text-transform: uppercase;
     padding: 0 2rem 0 var(--font-size-title);
}
 .header-logo-content-logo span {
     color: var(--color-tertiary);
     font-size: 3rem;
     font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}
 .header-logo-content-p {
     font-size: calc(1rem + 2vw);
     font-weight: 500;
     padding: 2vh 2rem 6vh var(--font-size-title);
}
 .header-logo-content-link:link, .header-logo-content-link:visited {
     margin-left: var(--font-size-title);
     border: 0.2rem solid var(--color-tertiary);
}
 .header-logo-content-link:link::before, .header-logo-content-link:visited::before {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: var(--color-tertiary);
     transform: scaleX(0);
     transition: transform 0.45s cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
     z-index: -1;
}
 .header-logo-content-link:hover::before, .header-logo-content-link:active::before {
     transform: scaleX(1);
}
 p {
     color: var(--color-secondary);
}
 a:link, a:visited {
     color: var(--color-quaternary);
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: calc(0.5rem + 1vw);
     padding: 1rem 2rem;
     border-radius: 0.3rem;
     position: relative;
     transition: all var(--transition-duration) cubic-bezier(1, 0, 0, 1);
     z-index: 1;
}
 #button {
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     place-self: bottom;
     align-items: center;
     justify-content: center;
     min-height: 25vh;
     font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
     flex-wrap: wrap;
}
 .switch {
     background-color: #333;
     color: #fff;
     border: none;
     outline: none;
     padding: 15px 30px;
     font-size: 20px;
     margin-top: 40px;
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .color {
     font-size: 50px;
}
 li {
     list-style: none;
     margin-bottom: 4rem;
}
 .header-main-nav {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     z-index: 6;
}
 .header-main-nav input[type="checkbox"] {
     position: absolute;
     top: 3rem;
     left: 3px;
     height: 40px;
     width: 40px;
     opacity: 0;
     cursor: pointer;
     z-index: 3;
}
 .header-main-nav-hamburger {
     position: absolute;
     top: 3rem;
     left: 3rem;
     height: 40px;
     width: 40px;
     padding: 1rem;
     background-color: var(--color-tertiary);
     z-index: 2;
     display: grid;
     display: flex;
     place-items: center;
     animation: main-nav 2s;
}
 @keyframes main-nav {
     0% {
         transform: translateX(150rem) rotate(1000deg);
         opacity: 0%;
    }
     100% {
         transform: translateX(0) rotate(0);
         opacity: 1;
    }
}
 .header-main-nav-hamburger > div {
     position: relative;
     height: 0.3rem;
     width: 100%;
     background-color: var(--color-secondary);
     display: grid;
     transition: var(--transition-duration) ease-in-out;
}
 .header-main-nav-hamburger > div::before, .header-main-nav-hamburger > div::after {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: -1rem;
     width: 60%;
     height: inherit;
     background-color: inherit;
     z-index: 2;
}
 .header-main-nav-hamburger > div::before {
     left: 0;
}
 .header-main-nav-hamburger > div::after {
     top: 1rem;
     right: 0;
}
 .header-main-nav input[type=checkbox]:checked + .header-main-nav-hamburger > div {
     transform: rotate(135deg);
}
 .header-main-nav input[type=checkbox]:checked + .header-main-nav-hamburger > div::before {
     left: 0;
     top: 0;
     width: 100%;
     transform: rotate(270deg);
}
 .header-main-nav input[type=checkbox]:checked + .header-main-nav-hamburger > div::after {
     opacity: 0;
}
 .header-main-nav input[type=checkbox]:checked:hover + .header-main-nav-hamburger > div {
     transform: rotate(405deg);
}
 .header-main-nav-menu {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     visibility: hidden;
     display: grid;
     place-items: center;
}
 .header-main-nav-menu > div {
     background-color: var(--color-secondary-m-dark);
     height: 200%;
     width: 200%;
     display: grid;
     place-items: center;
     transform: scaleX(0);
     transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
     opacity: 70%;
}
 .header-main-nav-menu > div > div {
     text-align: center;
     max-width: 90vw;
     max-height: 100vh;
     opacity: 1;
     transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .header-main-nav input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .header-main-nav-menu {
     visibility: visible;
}
 .header-main-nav input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .header-main-nav-menu > div {
     transform: scaleX(1);
    /*transition-duration: 0.5s;
    */
}
 .header-main-nav-menu ul li a:link, .header-main-nav-menu ul li a:visited {
     z-index: 5;
     font-size: 1.5rem;
     position: relative;
}
 .header-main-nav-menu ul li a:link::before, .header-main-nav-menu ul li a:visited::before {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     z-index: -1;
     transform: scaleY(0);
     background-color:crimson;
     transition: transform var(--transition-duration) ease-in-out;
}
 .header-main-nav-menu ul li a:hover::before, .header-main-nav-menu ul li a:active:before {
     transform: scaleY(1) 
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 485px) {
     .header-logo-content {
         grid-template-rows: max-content;
    }
     .header-logo-content h1 p{
         width: 10vh;
         text-align: center;
         word-wrap: normal;
         font-size: calc(1rem +1vh);
         word-wrap: initial;
    }
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
     .header-logo-content-title {
         padding-top: 0;
         grid-template-columns: 1fr minmax(10rem, 1fr) 1fr;
    }
     .header-logo-content-content-p {
         font-size: 2rem;
    }
     h1 {
         font-size: 1.8vh;
    }
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
     .header-logo-content-title {
         padding-bottom: 0;
         font-size: calc(1rem+2vw);
    }
     .header-main-nav-hamburger, .header-main-nav input[type="checkbox"] {
         left: 10px;
         top: 2rem;
    }
}
 @media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
     a:link, a:visited {
         font-size: calc(1rem + 1vw);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <title>Site</title>
      <meta name="description" content="">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
   </head>
   <main>
      <body class="container">
         <header id="home">
            <!--Nav-->
            <nav class="header-main-nav">
               <input type="checkbox" />
               <div class="header-main-nav-hamburger">
                  <div></div>
               </div>
               <div class="header-main-nav-menu">
                  <div>
                     <div>
                        <ul>
                           <li><a href="#">L1</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">L2</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">L3</a></li>
                           <li><a href="#">L4</a></li>
                        </ul>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </nav>
            <div class="header-logo-content">
               <a href="#" class="header-logo-content-logo">
               <span>Ho</span><span>me</span></a
                  >
               <div class="header-logo-content-content">
                  <h1 class="header-logo-content-title">Welcome to the page</h1>
                  <p class="header-logo-content-p">
                     A big ol menu
                  </p>
               </div>
            </div>
         </header>
   </main>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. your main tag overlaps your body tag, both the opening and closing of your main tag should be inside the body tag:

```
    <body>
      <main>
        <!-- other html tags here -->
      </main>
    </body>
```

2. add a space before and after your plus (+) signs:

```
    .header-logo-content-title {
         /* other styles */
         font-size: calc(1rem + 2vw);
    }
```

3. your media queries should 'cascade' - from the largest max-width to the smallest max-width - CSS style :)
4. in each media query define the width of 'header' or element with id='home' to have a with of 100vw:

```
    #home {
      width: 100vw;
    }
```

5. ensure the width of all elements in 'header' or id='home' is a percentage of its  parent - not also using vw;
6. if all of the above don't work - you can remove all padding and margin to see if that's where the problem is - comment all of them out or one by one until you find the guilty padding or margin;

I hope this helps ;)